# How to fix the error of debug module is not working in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, debugging

I am trying to use the debug module in my app.js file. But I am getting this error on running

```
set DEBUG=* & node app.js
```

This is the error I am getting

```
At line:1 char:13
+ set DEBUG=* & node app.js
+             ~
The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass 
it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I also tried this after seeing some posts

```
set DEBUG = app
```

But it still resulted in this error:

```
Set-Variable : A positional parameter 
cannot be found that accepts argument 'app'. 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalPar
   ameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com
  mands.SetVariableCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command as follow:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("DEBUG","express:*"); & npm start
```

Where 'express' is your app name defined in package.json.